# How to see only the first value and rest blank in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

How can i convert table 1 to table 2 in MS Access?
Table 1 is a regular table
In Table 2, sales_unit name is present only for the first entry, rest are blank.

From

```
agency  sales_unit  sales_rep
A4  ST7 Rep31
A4  ST7 Rep32
A4  ST7 Rep33
A4  ST7 Rep34
A4  ST7 Rep35
A4  ST8 Rep36
A4  ST8 Rep37
A4  ST8 Rep38
A4  ST8 Rep39
A4  ST8 Rep40
```

To

```
agency  sales_unit  sales_rep
A4  ST7 Rep31
A4      Rep32
A4      Rep33
A4      Rep34
A4      Rep35
A4  ST8 Rep36
A4      Rep37
A4      Rep38
A4      Rep39
A4      Rep40
```

Comment: Is this for a report?

Comment: no. this is just an example.

Comment: If you need this design as a table, there may be a need to rethink the overall design. Creating a query for this(table 2) would be much more difficult than it is worth.

Answer (score 3):

If its in a report, you can do it in one of two ways.

1. Use grouping and move the text box into the grouped header (e.g. you would say group on `sales_unit` and then move the sales unit text box into the `sales_unit` header section).
2. Set `HideDuplicates` to yes in the property sheet of a text box when looking at a report in design view.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. This is how it can be done.
Note: full_data is the table containing the entire data but the method is applicable generally.

```
SELECT t1.agency, t2.sales_unit, t1.sales_rep
FROM 
(SELECT agency, sales_unit, sales_rep FROM full_data WHERE agency='A4' GROUP BY agency, sales_unit, sales_rep ORDER BY agency, sales_unit, sales_rep) As t1 
 LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT agency, sales_unit, First(sales_rep) As FirstOfsales_rep FROM full_data WHERE agency='A4' GROUP BY agency, sales_unit) As t2 
 ON (t1.sales_rep = t2.FirstOfsales_rep) AND (t1.sales_unit = t2.sales_unit);
```

Comment: I would say this is dangerous and logically incorrect.  I maybe misunderstanding your need/purpose but I would say test this by switching the order of the Reps.  e.g. switch Rep 36 and Rep 37, you will see that this query will show Rep 36 under ST7 now.  Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: you are right. that is why i added order by clause. i am okay with reordering, infact it only helps in my analysis

Comment: Personally I don't see how ordering will help fix it.  Would you mind editing your answer with the new query?

Comment: i had edited before your comment. ordering will make sure that all similar agency & sales unit occur together so that the first sales_rep is the true first sales_rep. I have been using this trick in other languages (SAS etc) and very sure that this will always work. In fact many such operations in SAS depend on sorting so it is quite an accepted solution i would say.

Comment: I tried it, didn't work correctly for me, but hey if its working consistently for you then rock on!